# Running $(myfunction) returns "<filename>: command not found"

Tags: bash, function

I just started programming in bash today and there's a thing I can't figure out... Here is the script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=test.txt

test_file () {
  if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
     echo "$FILE exists"
  else
     echo "$FILE does not exist"
     return 1
  fi

  return
}

$(test_file)
```

When I run the script (named test) it outputs following error message:

```
"./test: line 16: test.txt: command not found"
```

To my amazement when I outcomment the "function parts" and replace return by exit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=test.txt

#test_file () {
  if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
     echo "$FILE exists"
  else
     echo "$FILE does not exist"
     exit 1
  fi

  exit
#}

#$(test_file)
```

it runs without any complaint. Even if I paste/yank the function with the function call into another script(which works just fine) amongst other functions it also works.

What am I missing?

Comment: In the future, paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and see what errors it flags (some are a little obscure for beginners to understand). If it's still not working, **then** post it here as a Q. Good luck and keep bashing away!

Comment: BTW, if you ran your script with `bash -x yourscript` to log each command run, that would have told you that it was trying to run `test.txt exists` as a command (or `test.txt does not exist`, as appropriate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run the *output* of your function as a command. Just drop the `$(...)`.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=test.txt

test_file () {
  if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
     echo "$FILE exists"
  else
     echo "$FILE does not exist"
     return 1
  fi

  return
}

test_file
```

Comment: And it works, thank you very much. I'll mark your answer as solution asap.